# Company VPN privacy

Tags: security, vpn, privacy

In order to connect from home using Microsoft Remote Desktop Connection Manager to the company network's servers we are using a VPN Client called NetExtender (SonicWall). While being connected to the VPN does it mean that any data leaving my home network (like surfing the web) would be traceable by the company or would this only be the case for RDP connections?

Thanks!

Comment: VPN clients usually have settings for "split tunneling" or gateway selection. they usually define what happens to traffic not destined for the VPN-connected subnet.

Comment: "oes it mean that any data leaving my home network (like surfing the web) would be traceable by the company or would this only be the case for RDP connections?" - Yes, this would be possible.  So don't do anything you wouldn't do at work.

Comment: This is weird, since it is my private computer at home. Anyway I will also check for the split tunneling or gateway selection at home and the IP address returned by the browser.

Answer (score -1):

It depends on the application, but most VPN clients would route your traffic via the VPN.

You can confirm this behaviour by typing "my ip" into google when not connected to the VPN and then after you connect to the VPN. If it changes, it is mostly likely that your internet traffic is going via the company VPN and therefore can be tracked.